# catalina.sh jdpa start doesn't start the server

Tags: apache, tomcat, remote-debugging

I was trying to debug the webapp so i wanted to attach remote debugger to apache tomcat. But when i run the command "catalina.sh jdpa start" it doesn't start the server instead it shows me this

./catalina.sh jdpa run 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/rsingh/work/apache-tomcat-7.0.27* 
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/rsingh/work/apache-tomcat-7.0.27 
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/rsingh/work/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/temp 
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home 
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/rsingh/work/apache-tomcat- 
7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/rsingh/work/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... ) 
commands: 
  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger 
  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager 
  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger 
  run               Start Catalina in the current window 
  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager 
  start             Start Catalina in a separate window
  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end
  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end
  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result
  version           What version of tomcat are you running?
Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that $CATALINA_PID is defined
*

I do not see the logs file being created for apache and i do not see any error in the syntax i am starting the server with. Has anyone ever faced it?

Answer (score 9):

You have a typo ("p" and "d" reversed). The command should be:
    catalina.sh jpda start